# How to call a view of another controller in mvc4

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have 2 controllers, `SearchController` and `DetailsController`.

the `SearchController` contains 2 views which contain form.

I want to redirect to a view of the details controller on the `[HttpPost]` action of my view in the SearchController

Is this possible???

Comment: You mean by returning an [RedirectResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult(v=vs.108).aspx)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) if you are doing some processing in the first controller and then sending the result to another controller.

**View**

```
using(@Html.BeginForm("firstaction", "search", FormMethod.Post)){

   // form stuff
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class SearchController
{

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult FirstAction()
      {
          // do initial processing in the first controller
          // e.g persisting changed on Edit Screen

          return RedirectToAction("SecondAction","Details");

      }
}

public class DetailsController
{
     public ActionResult SecondAction()
      {
          // do remaining processing in the first controller
          // fetching data for a grid and displaying the grid of items

          return View();
      }
}
```